# MPMediaPlayerViewController and Orientation changes in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I think I read all the topics here about playing a video with `MPMediaPlayerViewController` in SWIFT but didn't find my answer.

My main problem is about orientation: I have an embedded video that plays fine. When I rotate in `landscape mode` (right or left) I can play it directly in full screen but when I go back to `portrait` the video is not well embedded.

The video is inside of a black rectangle and not full in it.

Thank you very much for your help because I spent several days on this problem.

Regards

```
var moviePlayerController: MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()
let playerController:AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var filePath: NSURL!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("jojo", withExtension: "mov")

    self.moviePlayerController.contentURL = filePath
    self.moviePlayerController.prepareToPlay()
    self.moviePlayerController.repeatMode = .None
    self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)
    self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = .Fill //AspectFill ou  AspectFit
    self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = .None
    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

    var currentDevice = UIDevice.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange:" , name:
        UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }


func deviceOrientationDidChange(notify: NSNotification){

    var orientation:UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    switch (orientation) {
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.moviePlayerController.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)

        self.moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI / 2))
        break
    case .LandscapeRight:
        self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.moviePlayerController.setFullscreen(true, animated: true)
        self.moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2))
        break
    case .PortraitUpsideDown:
        //self.moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
        break
    case .Portrait:
        self.moviePlayerController.setFullscreen(false, animated: true)

        self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)

        self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = .Fill
        self.moviePlayerController.view.transform =     CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(2 * M_PI))
        self.view.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

        break
    default:
        println("Unknown orientation: \(orientation)")
    }

}
```